# Code review of my quick and dirty RESTful API Debugger

Tags: javascript, html

This is just a big HTML file that can be setup to test any RESTful API. The only change that needs to be made is updating the config array for any specific API you are developing.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>RESTful API Debugger</title>
    <style>
    label{ display:inline-block; width: 80px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    config = [
            {'file':  'auth.php',
             'get':   {'mime':false, 'vars':['em','pw']},
             'put':   {'mime':false, 'vars':['em','pw','newpw']},
             'delete':{'mime':false, 'vars':[]}},
            {'file':  'user.php',
             'post':  {'mime':false, 'vars':['fn','ln','em','pw','nn']},
             'get':   {'mime':false, 'vars':['em']},
             'put':   {'mime':false, 'vars':['fn','ln','em','nn']},
             'delete':{'mime':false, 'vars':['em','pw']}}
        ];




    // Quck and dirty object dump
    function dump(arr,level) {
        var dumped_text = "";
        if(!level) level = 0;

        //The padding given at the beginning of the line.
        var level_padding = "";
        for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

        if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects 
            for(var item in arr) {
                var value = arr[item];

                if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
                    dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
                    dumped_text += dump(value,level+1);
                } else {
                    dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
                }
            }
        } else { //Stings/Chars/Numbers etc.
            dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
        }
        return dumped_text;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // User clicked send, do the ajax
        $('#send').on('click', function() {
            var data = '';
            if ($('#var1').val() != '') {
                if (data != '') { data += ',\n'; } else { data = '{'; }
                data += "'" + $('#var1').val() + "':'" + $('#val1').val() + "'";
            }
            if ($('#var2').val() != '') {
                if (data != '') { data += ',\n'; } else { data = '{'; }
                data += "'" + $('#var2').val() + "':'" + $('#val2').val() + "'";
            }
            if ($('#var3').val() != '') {
                if (data != '') { data += ',\n'; } else { data = '{'; }
                data += "'" + $('#var3').val() + "':'" + $('#val3').val() + "'";
            }
            if ($('#var4').val() != '') {
                if (data != '') { data += ',\n'; } else { data = '{'; }
                data += "'" + $('#var4').val() + "':'" + $('#val4').val() + "'";
            }
            if ($('#var5').val() != '') {
                if (data != '') { data += ',\n'; } else { data = '{'; }
                data += "'" + $('#var5').val() + "':'" + $('#val5').val() + "'";
            }
            if ($('#var6').val() != '') {
                if (data != '') { data += ',\n'; } else { data = '{'; }
                data += "'" + $('#var6').val() + "':'" + $('#val6').val() + "'";
            }
            if (data != '') { data += ' }'; }
            if (data != '') {
                eval('data = ' + data);
            }
            $('#results').html('Sending Request...');
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", '');
                    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", $('#type').val());
                },
                'url': $('#url').val(),
                'type': $('#verb').val(),
                'data': data,
                'mimeType': 'multipart/form-data',
                'complete': function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    var msg = "Data: " + dump(data);
                    msg += "<br /><br />Status: " + jqXHR.status + " (" + jqXHR.statusText + " - " + textStatus + ")<br />";
                    msg += jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders().replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
                    msg += "---<br />" + jqXHR.responseText;
                    $('#results').html(msg);
                }
            });
        });

        // User chaged url, update verbs
        $('#url').on('change', function() {
            $('#verb').html('');
            for(i=0; i < config.length; i++) {
                restType = config[i];
                if(restType['file'] == $('#url').val()) {
                    if(typeof restType['get'] != 'undefined')
                    {
                        $('#verb').append('<option value="get">get</option>');
                    } else {
                        $('#verb').append('<option value="get">get (-)</option>');
                    }
                    if(typeof restType['post'] != 'undefined')
                    {
                        $('#verb').append('<option value="post">post</option>');
                    } else {
                        $('#verb').append('<option value="post">post (-)</option>');
                    }
                    if(typeof restType['put'] != 'undefined')
                    {
                        $('#verb').append('<option value="put">put</option>');
                    } else {
                        $('#verb').append('<option value="put">put (-)</option>');
                    }
                    if(typeof restType['delete'] != 'undefined')
                    {
                        $('#verb').append('<option value="delete">delete</option>');
                    } else {
                        $('#verb').append('<option value="delete">delete (-)</option>');
                    }
                }
            }
            $('#verb').change();
        });

        // User changed the verb, update variable names
        $('#verb').on('change', function() {
            $('#typelist').hide();
            for(j=1; j <= 6 ; j++) {
                $('#var' + j).val('');
                $('#val' + j).val('');
            }
            for(i=0; i < config.length; i++) {
                restType = config[i];
                if(restType['file'] == $('#url').val()) {
                    if(restType[$('#verb').val()]['mime'])
                        $('#typelist').show();
                    for(j=0; j < restType[$('#verb').val()]['vars'].length; j++) {
                        $('#var' + (j+1)).val(restType[$('#verb').val()]['vars'][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Add the pages
        for(i=0; i < config.length; i++) {
            restType = config[i];
            $('#url').append('<option>' + restType['file'] + '</option>');
        }
        $('#url').change();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="url">Url</label>
        <select id="url"></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="verb">Verb</label>
        <select id="verb">
            <option value="post">post</option><option value="get">get</option><option value="put">put</option><option value="delete">delete</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="typelist">
        <label for="type">Responce</label>
        <select id="type">
            <option>text/plain</option>
            <option>text/html</option>
            <option>application/xml</option>
            <option>application/json</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="var1">Variable 1:</label>
        <input id="var1" value="email" />
        <label for="val1">Value 1:</label>
        <input id="val1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="var2">Variable 2:</label>
        <input id="var2" value="hash" />
        <label for="val2">Value 2:</label>
        <input id="val2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="var3">Variable 3:</label>
        <input id="var3" />
        <label for="val3">Value 3:</label>
        <input id="val3" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="var4">Variable 4:</label>
        <input id="var4" />
        <label for="val4">Value 4:</label>
        <input id="val4" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="var5">Variable 5:</label>
        <input id="var5" />
        <label for="val5">Value 5:</label>
        <input id="val5" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="var6">Variable 6:</label>
        <input id="var6" />
        <label for="val6">Value 6:</label>
        <input id="val6" />
    </div>
    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <div id="results">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a lot of repeated code in there, you can easily clean up those ifs. Why are you using eval? There is no need for that,build the object instead of a string.

Comment: @epascarello: You should not answer the question in comments... why not just write up an answer?

Comment: Because my comment is not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @epascarello mentioned, there is a ton of repeated code here.

Some pointers if you wish:

You could consider to have the number of variables configurable. This means you can add that to your config object and then do the following in your `$(document).ready()`:

```
    var template =  '<div>' +
                      '<label for="var~">Variable ~:</label>' +
                      '<input  id="var~" value="email" />' +
                      '<label for="val~">Value ~:</label>' +
                      '<input  id="val~">' +
                    '</div>';
    for( var i = 0 ; i < config.parameterCount ; i++ ){
      $(body).append( template.replace( /~/g , i+1+"" );
    }
```

You could take this even further, and have the list of REST calls be a dropdown, then you could read from the config the required input fields and generate those at run time.

The same way, you could call this function in a loop :

```
function parseValue( index , data )
{
  var varId = '#var' + index;
  var valId = '#val' + index;

  if ($(varId).val() != '') {
    data = data ? data += ',\n' : '{';
    data += "'" + $(varId).val() + "':'" + $(valId).val() + "'";
  }
  return data;
}
```

or, since you need a data object in the data, you could have :

```
function parseValue( index , data )
{
  data = data || {}
  var varId = '#var' + index;
  var valId = '#val' + index;

  if ($(varId).val() != '')
    data[ $(varId).val() ] = $(valId).val();
}
```

Also the setting of the verb dropdown could be greatly improved:

```
function setVerbs( restType )
{
  "get,post,put,delete".split(",").forEach( function (verb)
  {
    var absenceIndicator = restType[verb] ? "" : " (-)";
    $('#verb').append('<option value="' + verb + '">' + verb + absenceIndicator +'</option>');
  });
}
```

**JSON**

Finally, I am wondering why you are not using the JSON functions that are available. You could replace the entirety of `dump` with `JSON.stringify`, you could replace your `eval` statement with `data = JSON.parse( data )`;